# Improve the efficiency of Spark SQL in repeated calls to groupBy/count. Pivot the outcome

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark DataFrame consisting of columns of integers. I want to tabulate each column and pivot the outcome by the column names.

In the following toy example, I start with this DataFrame `df`

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  1|  0|  2|
|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|
|  2|  2|  2|  3|  3|
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|
|  1|  1|  1|  0|  0|
|  3|  3|  3|  2|  2|
|  0|  1|  1|  1|  0|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Each cell can only contain one of `{0, 1, 2, 3}`. Now I want to tabulate the counts in each column. Ideally, I would have a column for each label `(0, 1, 2, 3)`, and a row for each column. I do:

```
val output = df.columns.map(cs => df.select(cs).groupBy(cs).count().orderBy(cs).
  withColumnRenamed(cs, "severity").
  withColumnRenamed("count", "counts").withColumn("window", lit(cs))
)
```

I get an Array of DataFrames, one for each row of the `df`. Each of these dataframes has 4 rows (one for each outcome). Then I do:

```
val longOutput = output.reduce(_ union _) // flatten the array to produce one dataframe
longOutput.show()
```

to collapse the Array.

```
+--------+------+------+
|severity|counts|window|
+--------+------+------+
|       0|     2|     a|
|       1|     3|     a|
|       2|     1|     a|
|       3|     1|     a|
|       0|     1|     b|
|       1|     4|     b|
|       2|     1|     b|
|       3|     1|     b|
...
```

And finally, I pivot on the original column names

```
longOutput.cache()
val results = longOutput.groupBy("window").pivot("severity").agg(first("counts"))

results.show()

+------+---+---+---+---+
|window|  0|  1|  2|  3|
+------+---+---+---+---+
|     e|  2|  2|  2|  1|
|     d|  3|  2|  1|  1|
|     c|  1|  4|  1|  1|
|     b|  1|  4|  1|  1|
|     a|  2|  3|  1|  1|
+------+---+---+---+---+
```

However the reduction piece took 8 full seconds on the toy example. It ran for over 2 hours on my actual data which had 1000 columns and 400,000 rows before I terminated it. I am running locally on a machine with 12 cores and 128G of RAM. But clearly, what I'm doing is slow on even a small amount of data, so machine size is not in itself the problem. The column groupby/count took only 7 minutes on the full data set. But then I can't do anything with that Array[DataFrame].

I tried several ways of avoiding *union*. I tried writing out my array to disk, but that failed due to a memory problem after several hours of effort. I also tried to adjust memory allowances on Zeppelin

So I need a way of doing the tabulation that does not give me an Array of DataFrames, but rather a simple data frame.

Comment: I gave you a possible solution taht's easy to implement. Let me know if it fixes your performance problem. If not, we'll try to find something else ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you trigger one spark job per column and then a big union. In general, it's much faster to try and keep everything within the same one.

In your case, instead of dividing the work, you could explode the dataframe to do everything in one pass like this:

```scala
df
    .select(array(df.columns.map(c => struct(lit(c) as "name", col(c) as "value") ) : _*) as "a")
    .select(explode('a))
    .select($"col.name" as "name", $"col.value" as "value")
    .groupBy("name")
    .pivot("value")
    .count()
    .show()
```

This first line is the only one that's a bit tricky. It creates an array of tuples where each column name is mapped to its value. Then we explode it (one line per element of the array) and finally compute a basic pivot.

Comment: I have tried this out and it works well -- huge increase in efficiency. Thanks.